# wamp mySQL error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver, mysql-error-1045

I have recently installed Windows Web Matrix in order to use Joomla but then I was instructed to download wamp instead. However I had problems installing it and then I figured that it was because Web Matrix was still installed. Therefore, I un-installed it and all the components it added.

Then, I tried re-installing wamp and it worked. However, I am having problems.

I can enter localhost but I can't enter phpMyAdmin :

http://www.speedyshare.com/files/29980627/Wamp_errors.docx

(Click on the file wamperrors.docx to see the images)

I have a feeling I might have deleted something related to mySQL when I deleted the programs by WebMatrix but I'm not certain.

Does anyone have any clue as to how I can get phpMyAdmin to work for me?

Thanks :)

---

I have made these changes but I'm still getting the same error :/ Here is my config.inc/php file:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';


/* rajk - for blobstreaming */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';


?>
```

Comment: Also add your images to stackoverflow so that it won't get deleted in a few months. Other people (with the same problem as you) might want to read this question aswell in the future. Use CTRL + G to add an image

Comment: I can't add an image cos I need 10 reputation :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [wamp mySQL error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121390/wamp-mysql-error)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, when you uninstalled WWM, you also removed MySQL. Be default MySQL keeps your databases and users saved even if you uninstall it.

To fix this, you need to set the right password for phpMyAdmin.

Stop all services (apache, mysql etc.)
Open '\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php' with notepad

lookup the lines:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; // MySQL password <-- type your new root
```

And set your new password

Comment: I have made these changes but I'm still getting the same error :/ Here is my config.inc/php file: (See code I posted)

Comment: I also manage to enter mySQL console but I dont know what use it has